# Attach UINavigationBar to UIScrollView to get shrinking title

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit, uinavigationbar

I have a UIViewController with a UITableView inside. I am required to have this in a UIViewController and not in a UINavigationController to support some other features in the design of the app. In iOS 11 and later, Apple introduced a large title effect to UINavigationBars that shrinks when the user scrolls down. How can I achieve this behaviour without using a UITableViewController?

Comment: What you want actually? Can you upload pic if possible?

Comment: On your iOS device, open the settings app and scroll down. Notice how the navigation bar shrinks when you scroll. This can be achieved by having a UINavigationController with a UITableViewController as its root. How can I do this with a UINavigationController and a UIViewController with a scrollview/tableview in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just put a UITableView/ Scroll view and give bottom and top constraints with respect to superview as 0.

And when presenting this page put it inside as rootViewController in let rootVc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: 'your view controller')
also enable rootVC.preferredLargeTitle = true

So if your tableView has more cells and when you scroll the navigation bar will shrink by itself.

Comment: I can't get this to work - I have set up my constraints as suggested in a new iOS application and although the content starts below the navigation bar, the navigation bar doesn't 'collapse'

Comment: will share a git link in sometime with sample code if fine?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I got it to work based on your sample project. Do you know if there is any way to keep this behaviour if a view is added below the scrollview? It stops working if this happens.

Comment: I think in scrollViewDidScroll we can detect if scrolling happened and then we toggle the navBar preferred titles property but i have not tried this i will try today and update my code.

Comment: It worked without writing an extra line of code wohoo you can checkout my same git repo for sample

Comment: Can you share the link to the said repo sample? thanks a bunch

Comment: it was long back but I think this was the project - https://github.com/dwivediashish00/navBarLargeTitlesStackAnswer/tree/master/LargeTitleApplication

Comment: That helped, great share!